# Experimental errors and significant figures

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

Textbooks indicate that when reporting experimental results, the number of decimal places in the best estimate of the value (mean) should be the same as that in the standard error, e.g. 9.81 $\pm$ 0.03. So can anyone explain why the results are presented as shown below (in Mössbauer's original paper), with different numbers of decimal places in each part of the values given?

[image: Mössbauer paper]

Comment: The simple stuff we say in schoolwork is just too simple. Especially for when it is something like $\pm0.095$ to $\pm0.14$, the 2nd digit for the uncertainty gives particularly more information than if you just rounded it to 1sf as schoolwork dictates it to be. In practical work, when the uncertainties must be handled carefully, it is typical for real world data to come with a bit more digits, to help users get things correct.

Comment: Ok, but what is, for example, 0.241 $\pm$ 0.40 supposed to indicate in the table? That the value could be between -0.159 and 0.641?

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Comment: That paper is a bit old and it might not be doing things as we now would do it. The scheme we now realise should be the correct thing to do, is to model the uncertainty as a Gaußian, so something like 68% chance that the value is between (-.159,.641) because of the [68-95-99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)

Answer (score 0):

> So can anyone explain why the results are presented as shown below (in Mössbauer's original paper), with different numbers of decimal places in each part of the values given?

This is basically just an historical question. Before the 1950’s it was not common to even report or analyze the experimental uncertainty. Mossbauer’s paper was in 1958. The best practices that we take as common knowledge now were not established by that time.

Answer (score -1):

The key to understanding what Mössbauer was doing is to subtract the value in the second column from the value in the first column and put the value in the third column.

For example, $1.346-1.074=0.272$, and note that you are subtracting two rough equal values each of which have error which are comparable with the result after subtraction.
The value in the third column has an estimate of the error in the subtraction $\sqrt{0.31^2+ 0.24^2} = 0.39$ which massively increases the percentage error.

I have no idea as to what the column headings mean but in the end by finding the average of all his values in the last column he was able to estimate a value of $M/v$ with an error of about $25\%$.

Column four is interesting in that the equal weight average value is $0.313$ and not the reported $0.268$.

As shown in the spreadsheet below, Mössbauer used a weighted average with the weight being the inverse of the error squared, ie he used $\text{value}/\text{error}^2$.

See [Weighted average from errors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101139/weighted-average-from-errors).

[image]

I leave showing that the standard error in the mean is $\pm 0.07$ to the reader!

Comment: So why -1?  What is wrong with what I have written as I think that I have explained how the table was constructed including the reason for the large increase in the fractional errors as a result of a subtraction of two similar values.